# non-central Chi-square distribution

Tags: distributions, non-central, chi-squared-distribution

If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where $\mu > 0$ and $\sigma > 2$, how do I find the PDF of $X^2$, and will it correspond to non-central Chi-square distribution?

Comment: Your questions are answered in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution).

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment but in article indicates unit variance, how does variance fit in the PDF

Comment: It merely establishes the units in which $X$ is measured and therefore is extremely easy to incorporate in all formulas.

Comment: @AhmedCheema make sure my edits were right. In particular the one with $\sigma >  2$.